# Combine multiple CSV files into...with a max size limit

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I am looking for an R solution, or Python solution, to combine several thousand CSV files into a few larger files, with a size limit of 1GB.  I have several scripts that merge all CSV files in a folder into one single CSV file, but this one file will probably be too big to work with, so I'd like to merge like 10, 11, 12, files, or whatever, up to around 1GB, save that file, and then start merging multiple remaining files into a second CSV around 1GB, save that one, and so on and so forth.  I googled around for a while and couldn't find a solution for this.

My code to combine multiple CV files into one single file looks like this.  Obviously there are multiple ways of doing essentially the same thing, so I'm sure there are mostly similar, but slightly different, ways to do this kind of thing.

I think the code will look something like this, based on Shree's comments below.

```
setwd("C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test")

# assuming all files are in working directory
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")

file_sizes <- sapply(files, function(x) file.size(x)) # sizes in bytes
cum_sizes <- cumsum(file_sizes)

file_read_groups <- cut(cum_sizes, breaks = seq(0, max(cum_sizes), by = min(500000, max(cum_sizes))))

# code to read and combine CSV from each file group which you already have
txt_files <- list.files()
list_of_reads <- lapply(files, readLines)

for(i in 1:length(list_of_reads)){
    df_of_reads <- data.frame(file_name = txt_files, contents = do.call(rbind, files))
    write.csv(df_of_reads, "csv" + toString(i) + ".csv", row.names = F)
    next
  }
```

However, that script throws up this error message.

```
Error in do.call(rbind, files) : second argument must be a list
```

I thought the second argument was a list...

Comment: in R, you can try using `file.size()` function to get sizes of all your files in a directory and then group and read them such that each group size is <= 1GB.

Comment: An alternative solution is to combine all CSV and save it in a database, such as sqlite, R has [a nice interface for that](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSQLite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building a data frame of your files and meta data. Then, run `by` to read files and save by groups. Below does not guarantee equal-sized files but does output CSV files in 1GB-byte blocks.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")                 # csvs in work directory    
file_sizes <- file.size(files)                        # sizes in bytes (no sapply needed)
cum_sizes <- cumsum(file_sizes)                       # cumulative bytes
file_read_groups <- as.integer(cum_sizes / 1e9)       # floor multiples of 1 GB

# FILE DATA FRAME BUILD
files_df <- data.frame(files, file_sizes, cum_sizes, file_read_groups, 
                       row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# PROCESS BY GROUP   
output <- by(files_df, files_df$file_read_groups, function(sub) {                  
    # READ CSVs AND BIND IN ONE DATA FILES
    tmp <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sub$files, read.csv))

    # EXPORT FILE TO DISK
    write.csv(tmp, paste0(sub$file_read_groups[[1]], ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)  
})
```

Comment: Hello there.  This seems like the right approach, Parfait, but when I run that code I get the following error:   Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection 
Everything up to 'files_df' works fine.  However, the saving by groups does not work.  Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Try adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame()` call since files are stored as factors.

Comment: That does appear to be working!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help.

Comment: Yeah, man, really nice concept.  I up-voted a bunch of things for you over time; lots in the Exvcel-VBA and Access-VBA groups.  Some in the Python/R groups.  You really know a lot about a lot!!

Comment: Haha. Thanks! I try. I remember you on several tags as well. Keep working across stacks. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, something like this should work out -

```
# assuming all files are in working directory
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
file_sizes <- sapply(files, function(x) file.size(x)) # sizes in bytes
cum_sizes <- cumsum(file_sizes)
file_read_groups <- cut(cum_sizes, breaks = seq(0, max(cum_sizes), by = min(1e9, max(cum_sizes))))
# code to read and combine CSV from each file group which you already have
```

Comment: Thanks.  This definitely looks promising.  I'm wondering how to incorporate your code into my own code.  I don't see any apparent way to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: I modified the code in my original post, based on your suggestions.  Now I'm getting a new error.  Do you see it?  Do you know what's going on?  Thanks.